# WPF: MVVM - Disable command attached button on ivalueconverter convert exception

Tags: wpf, mvvm, button, command, ivalueconverter

I have a simple scenario and a issue with it which I just cant seem to resolve past few days.

OK, first of all I use MVVM to bind my View on a ViewModel. I have in my view several text boxes which binds to several properties (most strings) in ViewModel (binds actually to an Custom Object (type Person, name SelectedPerson) with strings properties , object which is a property of the viewmodel). This object implements INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo. It has also an int property named Age. I also have in my view a button which is bound to a command in my viewmodel, a command which inside CanExecute test the SelectedPerson's properties and return true if all are correct.

Now my issue is: if I put in my Age text box from my View something not int, a red tectagle will appear (is normal, because there is an exception to the conversion), but in that specific moment, to the object behind (SelectedPerson, type Person) there isn't sent the newValue (the setter to that property Age, or the  IDataErrorInfo Members don't intercept the value .... I guess it is normal because there isn't any "new" value, because I put an incorrect format in the text box in the first place).

So, maybe I repeat myself, the issue is: if the new Age (new incorrect Age) isn't set, then the Object behind still hold last value, which if it was correct then the command itself it's correct (the can execute will return true) and the button is **enabled**

As you can imagine I want the submit button (it's a button which saves current person details in data storage module) to be disabled when current properties don't pass through conversions methods.

PS: I used a IValueConverter class , and on that text box binded to Age, I made use of my StringToIntConverter class....but on Convert Method I don't know how to pass the SelectedPerson binded object  (I just pass the text value, and return the int value)

I guess one way to do it could be by using MultiBinding scenario , but I'm not sure.

If I could pass the SelectedPerson inside Convert method from that converter I could invalidate that command from the converter itself.

Sorry for my English, I know it's far from perfect :) and thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution would be to bind the textbox to a string property instead, and update your view model so that your IDataErrorInfo implementation for that property name attempts a string to int conversion and returns the result of that.  Your CanExecute test would also then include this conversion as part of the validation test.